# DatePicker Formatting

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I realise this question has *most likely* been asked many times before, but I can't seem to find a simple, definitive answer.

I have a DatePicker in C# (WPF) that when I show its content is printed like this: `30 October 2015`

This is obviously an issue when I come to convert it, which I try to do like so;

```
newJob.DateCreated = DateTime.ParseExact(createdPicker.Text, "YYYY-MM-DD", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This throws an error `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` which I assume comes about because it doesn't understand `October` instead of `10`.

How would I format this correctly?

Comment: Don't try to convert the text to a datetime, use the datetime object, for example, the DatePicker's SelectedDate property.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "dd MMMM yyyy"?

Comment: Also, you are trying to convert from YYYY-MM-DD which is year-month-day and your string is day-month-year

Comment: Why aren't you binding to the selected date property? Moreover the format you are using is wrong, try changing the format

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment from Dugas. This should work.

```
newJob.DateCreated = createdPicker.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```